# JS - Thin number of points based on density

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array as follows (each small array is `[x, y]`):

```
var myPoints = [[25, 28], [26, 26], [70, 40], [50, 50], [300, 300], [285, 350], [1000, 1000]];
```

Let's say I need to thin the array down to 4 points. (this is a small example, my acutal array has thousands of points) How could I go about thinning the array based on density so more points are removed from areas with points closer together and less points are removed from areas with lower density?

In this case (reducing the above array from 8 to 4 items) I would expect the returned array to look something like the following:

```
var thinnedPoints = [[25, 28], [70, 40], [300, 300], [1000, 1000]];
```

My idea on how to approach this would be to generate a dictionary that maps the point to it's minimum distance to another point (e.g. a point close to another point would have a small minimum distance) then sort the dictionary based on ascending minimum distance, then remove every n'tn item of the dictionary.

The problem with this approach is I don't know how to efficiently generate the *distance to closest other point* value for each point.

Is there an efficient way to generate those values or maybe is there another way to approach this density based thinning problem?

Thanks!

Comment: _"thinning the array based on density so more points are removed from areas with points closer together and less points are removed from areas with lower density?"_ Not certain gathering logic which results in `[[25, 28], [70, 40], [300, 300], [1000, 1000]]`? What do you mean by "closer together" ? Could the result alternatively be `[[26, 26], [70, 40], [285, 350], [1000, 1000]]`?

Comment: By "closer together" do you mean `[25, 28]` are close or `[25, 28], [26, 26]` are close?

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have specified further. `[25, 28]` is an `[x, y]` point. I am not comparing the x coordinate to the y coordinate. I am comparing the points to other points so I am comparing `[25, 28]` to `[26, 26]`.

Comment: Will the array always be arranged from least values to greatest values?

Comment: No. I only arranged them as such in the example for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to solve either a P-center problem or a P-median problem.

From [Approximability Results for the `p`-Center Problem](http://www.stefan.buettcher.org/cs/p-center.pdf) by Stefan Buettcher,

> The `p`-Center problem, also known as the Min-Max Multicenter problem
>   or the Facility Location problem, is a famous problem from operations
>   research. Informally, it is the problem of placing fire stations in a
>   city so that the maximum time to reach any point in the city is
>   minimized.

From [Methods for Solving the `p`-Median Problem: An Annotated Bibliography](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/tumath/research/reports/report96.pdf) by J. Reese,

> The `p`-median problem is simply stated as: Given a graph or a network
>   `G = (V, E)`, find `Vp ⊆ V` such that `|Vp| = p`, where `p` may either
>   be variable or fixed [...], and that the sum of the shortest distances
>   from the vertices in `{V\Vp}` to their nearest vertex in `Vp` is
>   minimized.

Both problems are NP-complete in general, so there is no (known) way to solve them in polynomial time. But there are various heuristics you could try.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and efficent solution that works especially well on large sets is to just pick the points randomly. This implicitly removes less points from regions containing less points than elsewhere - which seems to be just what you want, if you only want to scale the density linearly. It should yield the same results as your approach, without needing to calculate any distances.

If the data is not ordered in any way (i.e. already random), you can also drop every second point or just the first or second half.

If you want to tweak the density distribution non-linearly, you could divide the set into multiple regions (e.g. squares) small enough so that the density is roughly uniform in each of them, and then drop every n-th of the points per region. If you choose the region size appropriately, this approach might also deliver better (and more consisten) results than the purely random one on smaller data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for..of` loop, `for` loop, `.map()`, `Math.min()`, `.filter()`.

Loop through each element of array, assign `x`, `y` to separate array variables; subtract the difference between each element in `x` or `y` arrays; map original array, begin by removing first or second element of matched pair where the two elements have the least numeric difference between any other number in array; that is, the two numbers are separated by the least amount of digits. Continue removing elements, as distance between numbers increases, until `n`, here, `3`, elements are removed from original array.

For example, mapping `x` can return either

```
  [[25, 28], [70, 40], [300, 300], [1000, 1000]];
```

or

```
  [[26,26], [50,50], [285,350], [1000,1000]]
```

as the range between the numbers is the same each in direction

```
  [1, 1, 20, 20, 15, 15, 700]
```

```js
var myPoints = [
  [25, 28],
  [26, 26],
  [70, 40],
  [50, 50],
  [300, 300],
  [285, 350],
  [1000, 1000]
];

var [x, y] = [
  [],
  []
];

var [xx, yy] = [
  [],
  []
 ];

for (let z of myPoints) {
  [x, y] = [
    [...x, z[0]],
    [...y, z[1]]
  ];
}

var stop = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var prop = x[i];
  if (typeof xx[i] !== "object") {
    xx[i] = {
      index: i,
      diff: [],
      value: prop
    };
  }

  for (var len = 0; len < x.length; len++) {
    var key = x[len];
    xx[i].diff.push(
      prop > key 
      ? prop - key 
      : key > prop ? key - prop : Infinity
    )
  }
}

var range = xx.map(prop => Math.min.apply(Math, prop.diff));
var temp = range.slice(0);

for (var i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
  var curr = Math.min.apply(Math, temp);
  var index = temp.indexOf(curr);
  temp[index] = Infinity;
  var pair = Math.min.apply(Math, temp);
  var next = temp.indexOf(pair);
  temp[next] = Infinity;
  x[next] = void 0;
};

var res = myPoints.map((prop, index) => 
            x[index] === undefined ? null : prop).filter(Boolean);

console.log(res);
```

usage as a function

```js
var myPoints = [
  [25, 28],
  [26, 26],
  [70, 40],
  [50, 50],
  [300, 300],
  [285, 350],
  [1000, 1000]
];

var filter = (arr, xy, n) => {

  var [x, y] = [
    [],
    []
  ];

  var [xx, yy] = [
    [],
    []
  ];

  for (let z of arr) {
    [x, y] = [
      [...x, z[0]],
      [...y, z[1]]
    ];
  }

  var XY = {
    "x": [x, xx],
    "y": [y, yy]
  };

  var item = XY[xy];
  var stop = n;
  for (var i = 0; i < item[0].length; i++) {
    var prop = item[0][i];
    if (!item[1][i]) {
      item[1][i] = {
        index: i,
        diff: [],
        value: prop
      };
    }

    for (var len = 0; len < item[0].length; len++) {
      var key = item[0][len];
      item[1][i].diff.push(
        prop > key ? prop - key : key > prop ? key - prop : Infinity
      )
    }
  }
  
  var range = item[1].map(prop => Math.min.apply(Math, prop.diff));
  var temp = range.slice(0);

  for (var i = 0; i < stop; i++) {
    var curr = Math.min.apply(Math, temp);
    var index = temp.indexOf(curr);
    temp[index] = Infinity;
    var pair = Math.min.apply(Math, temp);
    var next = temp.indexOf(pair);
    temp[next] = Infinity;
    item[0][next] = void 0;
  };

  return arr.map((prop, index) => 
    item[0][index] === undefined ? null : prop).filter(Boolean);
}

console.log(filter(myPoints, "x", 3));
```